# Docker container for Android : Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

Tags: android, docker

I am try to build android on Docker container, I am getting every time this error for `./gradlew assembleDebug`

> :saltside-android:transformClassesWithDexForBikroyDebugThe message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
>   Build request sent: BuildAndStop{id=81f2e456-bb5b-4cf8-9190-3c8b22e286b6.1, currentDir=/app/project-main}
>   Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
>   Daemon pid: 35
>     log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/3.3/daemon-35.out.log
>   ----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-35.out.log -----
>   :saltside-android:processBugsnagBikroyDebugManifest
>   :saltside-android:processBikroyDebugResources
>   :saltside-android:generateBikroyDebugSources
>   :saltside-android:incrementalBikroyDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
>   :saltside-android:javaPreCompileBikroyDebug
>   :saltside-android:compileBikroyDebugJavaWithJavacNote: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   :
>   :saltside-android:compileBikroyDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :saltside-android:compileBikroyDebugSources
>   :saltside-android:mergeBikroyDebugShaders
>   :saltside-android:compileBikroyDebugShaders
>   :saltside-android:generateBikroyDebugAssets
>   :saltside-android:mergeBikroyDebugAssets
>   :saltside-android:processBugsnagBikroyDebugProguard
>   :saltside-android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForBikroyDebug
>   :saltside-android:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForBikroyDebug
>   :saltside-android:transformClassesWithDexForBikroyDebug
>   ----- End of the daemon log -----
>   :
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   :
>   * What went wrong:
>   Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
>   :
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I already increased memory and disabled daemon in *gradle.properties* like this

```
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

Any body know what can be solution for it?

Comment: Can you share you docker file ?

Comment: @Shantanu For testing I tried third-part docker images but having same issue, my Dockerfile  is like this                                                                `FROM runmymind/docker-android-sdk:latest

ADD . /app`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the solution but still wrote an answer so that anybody has the same problem and can solve it.
It was due to memory size of docker container, I am using `mac` and looks like issue is with `mac` machine only.
On `mac` by default container size was 2GB, you can check on docker container with `free` command. so increase it to 4GB or more, boom it will solve your problem.

```
Docker->Preferences->Advanced->Memory
```

[image: Click on Preferences]

[image: Increase Memory]

Comment: perfect tried many solutions but this resolved the error for me.

Comment: after a day of trying everything, your answer saved me. you rock!